# Inserting elements into page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an empty `div` on my page which I want to insert content into using jQuery.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

After inserting the first lot of content, I'd like my markup to look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inserted first">blah</div>
</div>
```

Round 2 of inserting content I'd like it to be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inserted second">blah</div>
    <div class="inserted first">blah</div>
</div>
```

Round 3 of inserting content I'd like it to be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inserted third">blah</div>
    <div class="inserted second">blah</div>
    <div class="inserted first">blah</div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

So far I have tried `$(data).appendTo($(".container").before(".inserted"));` but that doesn't work.

**Update:** Thanks for all of your answers. Pretty much all answers so far work. I had to pick one so went for the oldest first. Thanks again to everyone for your help.

Comment: Look at [jQuery prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to insert content before the current child. What you need is the [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function:

```
$(".container").prepend(data);
// assuming data is <div class="inserted second">blah</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, `data` is the div with the `.inserted class` - i'm using this in an AJAX success function. `data` is what is echo'd by my PHP handler

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) instead of `.appendTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepend instead of append. Assuming data contains the HTML of 
`<div class="inserted x">blah</div>`

You can use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$(".container").prepend(data);
```

Or [prependTo()](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/):

```
$(data).prependTo(".container");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.container').prepend(DOM object or html string);
```

For example:

```
$('.container').prepend('<div class="inserted third">blah</div>');
```